Подсчитать число комбинаций в множестве
Есть множество из 20 ячеек в которых возможно 2 значения 1 или 0
Количество возможных  уникальных комбинаций 2^20=1048576 .
Если объединить все комбинации которые имеют одинаковое количество единиц в одну группу( объединяем все комбинации с двумя единицами и 18ю нулями, тремя единацами и 17ю нулями и т д ) то количество уникальных групп будет 21( одна в которой 19 единиц, одна в которой 20 единиц И так далее)

Вопрос

как подсчитать колво уникальных комбинаций для каждой из 21й группы:
Колво уникальных комбинаций в которых 1 единица и 19 нулей-?
Колво уникальных комбинаций в которых 2 единицы и 18 нулей-?
И так далее… что в сумме должно дать 2^20=1048576

Вам же уже ответили https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

В вашем случае для комбинации из 2 единиц и 18 нулей будет 20! / (2! * 18!) = 190

@alexey ten сошлось❤️
